# How to delete text before and after a symbol "_" and "-"?

Tags: excel, vba

I got a list where I want to delete certain text

1. HY_5AP001KL10   Output 5AP001KL10
2. 5AP0015K20_HY   Output 5AP0015K20
3. HW-5AP002H20    Output 5AP002H20
4. 5AP002lE_LEE SPRING    Output 5AP002lE
5. NAS4021-2E-12    Output   NAS4021-2E-12

In the above mentioned list I want to delete HY before and after along with the symbol `_` and HW before and after `-` and every thing after symbol `_` as LEE SPRING mentioned in 4th item and must not delete -2E or -12 for last item. Can someone please help on this. The above mentioned list will be single item per each cell.

Here is my code... but the problem is I am not able to delete text after "" as shown in list for item 4

```
Sub Replace_Characters() 
    row_number = 1 

    Do 

        DoEvents 

        row_number = row_number + 1 
        the_description = Sheet2.Range("A" & row_number) 
        the_description = Replace(the_description, "HY", "") 
        the_description = Replace(the_description, "HY-", "") 
        the_description = Replace(the_description, "_HY", "") 
        the_description = Replace(the_description, "-HY", "") 
        the_description = Replace(the_description, "HY", "") 
        Sheet2.Range("A" & row_number) = the_description 
    Loop Until row_number = 20 

End Sub
```

Comment: What is your code so far? What are you struggling with? Happy to look at your code, but nobody here will write it for you from scratch.

Comment: You will also get a bit further if you post the expected output for an item or two.  Textual descriptions of this sort can be difficult to understand.  Output is king.

Comment: Here is my code... but the problem is I am not able to delete text after "_" as shown in list for item 4
Sub Replace_Characters()

row_number = 1

Do
DoEvents
row_number = row_number + 1
the_description = Sheet2.Range("A" & row_number)
the_description = Replace(the_description, "HY_", "")
the_description = Replace(the_description, "HY-", "")
the_description = Replace(the_description, "_HY", "")
the_description = Replace(the_description, "-HY", "")
the_description = Replace(the_description, "HY", "")

Sheet2.Range("A" & row_number) = the_description

Loop Until row_number = 20

End Sub

Comment: @SaiRajesh I have formatted and moved your comment in your question. Code should always go with the question since comments make it difficult to format code.

Comment: @SaiRajesh If either of the answers helped you, could you please mark one as accepted?

Answer (score 0):

`left(the_description,instr(the_description,"_")-1)` will delete "_" and everything after it in your text.
If you do many replace like that, then maybe using regular expressions in VBA would be the ultimate solution for you. There are plenty of support materials on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend writing a function. Send the function the information you want and all the rules can just sit there like this:

```
Function CleanData(Description As String) As String

    Description = Replace(Description, "HY_", "", 1)
    Description = Replace(Description, "_HY", "")
    Description = Replace(Description, "HW-", "", 1)
    Description = Replace(Description, "-HY", "")

    Dim DescriptionArray() As String
    DescriptionArray = Split(Description, "_")
    Description = DescriptionArray(0)

    CleanData = Description

End Function

Sub Test()

    MsgBox CleanData("HY_5AP001KL10"), vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Expected: 5AP001KL10"
    MsgBox CleanData("5AP0015K20_HY"), vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Expected: 5AP0015K20"
    MsgBox CleanData("HW-5AP002H20"), vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Expected: 5AP002H20"
    MsgBox CleanData("5AP002lE_LEE SPRING"), vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Expected: 5AP002lE"
    MsgBox CleanData("NAS4021-2E-12"), vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Expected: NAS4021-2E-12"

End Sub
```

I have tested the 5 uses cases and the output looks fine to me, but please feel free to modify it to your needs.

Comment: Thank you for your support, I cannot apply function because this items will keep on changing and there will be big list. I have recorded a macro using find and replace example find ---> "_*" if I do this its deleting every thing after the symbol "_".